# What does this function callee init and clean up sequence do?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am using CompCert and it compiles

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

to

```
# File generated by CompCert 2.3pl2
# Command line: -S test2.c
    .text
    .align  16
    .globl main
main:
    .cfi_startproc
    subl    $12, %esp
    .cfi_adjust_cfa_offset  12
    leal    16(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 0(%esp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addl    $12, %esp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
    .type   main, @function
    .size   main, . - main
```

Note that this is the AT&T syntax.

What is this doing?

I am not familiar with the subl, leal, movl pattern.

I've only seen the

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
...
leave
```

pattern.

Comment: Nowadays, compilers prefer to adjust the stack pointer only once per function and not push and pop all the time. This seems to execute better on modern hardware (e.g. re instruction reordering), and it frees up an extra register (the *BP register).

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand what the code is doing when putting the address %esp + 16 on the top of the stack. I thought %esp before the function call would point to the function parameter, but this is %esp + 4. What is it pointing to?

Comment: I think that's the equivalent of storing the base pointer. Since the *BP registers are never used, this provides a copy of the stack frame base. But this is unoptimized code, so there may be no need for this. Try again with optimizations, and with code that contains actual function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ESP + 4]` points to return address on proc entry.
`[ESP + xx]` refers to proc input params
`[ESP - xx]` reserves place for local variables

[image]